# How to get ratio of sums 10% top and bottom each category from table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have table `employees` with columns `id`, `category`, `salary`.
I want to get ratio of salaries sums 10% top and bottom employees each category.
Quantity of employees each category are different.

```
╔══════╤════════╤════════╗
║id    │category│salary  ║
╠══════╪════════╪════════╣
║102329│1       │8995.00 ║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102330│2       │10069.00║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102331│2       │10076.00║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102332│3       │10516.00║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102334│3       │9285.00 ║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102335│3       │9786.00 ║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102336│1       │9056.00 ║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102337│4       │5695.00 ║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102338│4       │5369.00 ║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102339│3       │10499.00║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102340│3       │7540.00 ║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102341│3       │8245.00 ║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102342│3       │10089.00║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102343│4       │5631.00 ║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102344│4       │5674.00 ║
╟──────┼────────┼────────╢
║102345│3       │8607.00 ║
╚══════╧════════╧════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ntile` to break the salaries up to ten groups (deciles), and then sum the salaries in the top and bottom of each category:

```
WITH salaries AS (
    SELECT category, 
           salary
           NTILE(10) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY SALARY asc) AS decile
    FROM   employees
)
SELECT   category,
         SUM(salary) FILTER (WHERE decile = 1) /
         SUM(salary) FILTER (WHERE decile = 10) AS ratio
FROM     salaries
GROUP BY category
```